DJI cloud API Docker set up issue
I am following cloud api tutorial on dji docker, but getting this error

I have tried looking over the docker and the nginix image is there. What should I do to solve this issue and the load command works perfectly fine

Please don't include images of text. Put the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

I did ran into the same problem, you sure the load was working fine? 
I got the issue of wrong version 1.0.0 but the .tar is 1.9.0 
So it should look something like this:
sudo docker load < cloud_api_sample_docker_v1.9.0.tar

Another try would be to check up the docker file again and check internally the versions docker tries to download.
Good luck and happy to know if it worked/helped!

The version is correct, I am using Windows for this. The problem comes down as it says one of the image named "njinx" is not there
